# Converting a string to a bit sequence and vice versa

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, binary

What MATLAB functions should I use to convert a string into an array of binary digits according to symbols' ASCII codes (or any other character encoding table) and vice versa. For example:

```
str = 'ab';
bin = toBinSeq(str); % so that we get smth like bin=[ 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ]
str2 = backToStr(bin); % so that we get str2='ab'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually went with

```
function bin = str2bin(str)
bin = dec2bin(str, 8);
bin = bin(:)-'0';
```

and

```
function str = bin2str(bin)
str = char(bin2dec(reshape(char(bin+'0'), [], 8))');
```

Comment: Calling the str2bin function in Octave gives me the following error message:
error: dec2base: input must be real non-negative integers
error: called from
    dec2base at line 72 column 5
    dec2bin at line 50 column 7
    str2bin at line 2 column 5

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but it should be enough to get you there:

```
str = 'ab'
dec = double(str)
bin = dec2bin(str)
```

Comment: Why do you need dec = double(str)? The result is the same without it

Comment: @Glinka If the conversion happens implicitly, then you can of course skip that step in your implementation. I will leave it in the answer as a hint of what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Do not use double in the first step. While it seems to work in your case it is not pretty. Use `uint16` instead (since MATLAB chars is 2 bits and include some unicode characters `char(300)
`). Apart from this, good showing that additional conversion from string integer is not needed and that a string can be seens as a 16 bit integer

Comment: @patrik The reason that I showed `double` here is that this seems to be what matlab will do implicitly when given the choice. For instance: `class('ab'-char(0))` -- Of course it is unusual to use double for integer representation, but I believe it is consistent here. And all character codes can be represented as double without running into floating point issues etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13254605)

Comment: @iliketocode This does not tell the asker exactly what to do, but it is a partial answer that should (has proven to) be sufficient for the asker to solve his problem. It is my understanding that those sort of answers are acceptable (or even recommended sometimes to stimulate the asker), do you not agree?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, thank you for your time and attension. To be honest, your post was of a little use to me. Function *dec2bin* was known to me, but even if it weren't, it'd still be big leap separating it from an actual answer. It's a considerate comment, but it hardly can be passed for an answer, even partial.

Comment: @Glinka Sure, if you know the thing that I mention, then of course it is of little value. But if you read the question you may note that you do not show that you know this part (to be relevant) already. -- I will not defend this answer further, but have the following general advice: If you know part of the solution, it is highly recommended to include in your answer what you have come up with so far. That allows others to help you most efficiently.